# Fast Search is not working Error "search request was unable to execute on fast search server"

Tags: fast-search

I am facing this issue while searching for something below is the error message 
"The search request was unable to execute on FAST Search Server".

I have already refer below links but not useful

[FAST Search for SharePoint 2010](https://yihaa5.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010-query-return-the-search-request-was-unable-to-connect-to-the-search-service/)

[FSA: The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service (FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393738(v=office.14).aspx)

[FAST Search queries of SharePoint Server 2010 content generate an error in the Web browser: The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/04/20/fast-search-queries-of-sharepoint-server-2010-content-generate-an-error-in-the-web-browser-the-search-request-was-unable-to-connect-to-the-search-service/)

I have also tried with rebooting all the server (APP, DB, FAST Search Server).

Below is the error from ULS log

> Exception occurred while triggering query processor cache refresh for
>   application e3579d0e-7d22-48f0-93eb-edb01b387140:
>   System.ApplicationException: Error in the application. 
>       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ApplicationCacheRefresher._CacheRefreshCallback(Object
>   state, Boolean timedOut)

Please share your thoughts and useful links.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution for this issue is to Re-indexes all content from the pre-index content store (FiXML files) by using below command on Fast Search Server.

**C:\FASTSearch\bin\indexeradmin resetindex**

For more details refer below links

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943517(v=office.14).aspx

http://tracyswebdesign.blogspot.com/2013/08/stuck-index-for-fast-search-in.html